# Get Parent When Clicked Child Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with highchart, this is my code:

```
              categories = ['Position', 'Ages', 'Salary'],
                    data = [{
                        y: 120,
                        color: colors[0],
                        drilldown: {
                            name: 'Position',
                            categories: dataemp,
                            data: percent,                           
                            color: colors[1]
                        }
                    }, {
                        y: 120,
                        color: colors[4],
                        drilldown: {
                            name: 'Ages',
                            categories: ['10-20', '20-30', '30-40', '40-50', '50-60'],
                            data: [parseFloat(age[0]['percentA']), parseFloat(age[0]['percentB']), parseFloat(age[0]['percentC']), parseFloat(age[0]['percentD']), parseFloat(age[0]['percentE'])],
                            color: colors[2]
                        }
                    }
```

I want to show parent name, when I click the child, example the child name is `10-20` .And the output that i need is like:
`This 10-20 has parent : Ages`

Help me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Items',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Position',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'position'
            }, {
                name: 'Ages',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'ages'
            }, {
                name: 'Salary',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'salary'
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'position',
                data: [
                    ['position1', 50],
                    ['position2', 60],
                    ['position3', 25]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'ages',
                data: [
                    ['10-20', 20],
                    ['20-30', 30],
                    ['30-40', 50],
                    ['40-50', 60],
                    ['50-60', 25]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'salary',
                data: [
                    ['salary1', 50000],
                    ['salary2', 20000],
                    ['salary3',10000]
                ]
            }]
```

check this fiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/6fLhxy00/

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question, I want to get parent name when i clicked child.

Comment: Well sorry i din't understood your question yet. by default it will show parent -> on click of parent .i.e. Position or Ages or Salary you will get appropriate drill down. on click of child drill down again you need to get parent or in drill down do you want to display parent name ?

Comment: check this displaying parent name within drilldown http://jsfiddle.net/6fLhxy00/1/